# Storing types in an external / separate project

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, typescript2.0, npm-link

I have my types for a project in a separate codebase, because it's shared between multiple projects. I have the following directory structure in suman-types:

[image]

In my main project, I import suman-types, and in my main project's tsconfig.json file, I have this:

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/suman-types/dts"
    ],
```

I also tried this:

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/suman-types/dts/*"
    ],
```

unfortunately, the problem is that when I store the types in a different project and symlink that project to my main project, I can't get my main project to recognize the types and auto-import them as usual.

Does anyone know how to properly store types in a separate project?

Comment: Tried the same setup with Visual Studio Code and it works. Something to do WebStorm?

Comment: thanks, what did you put in your `typeRoots` in your tsconfig.json file in your main project?